# Validate xml signature with X509DATA and RSAKeyValue

Tags: c#, xml, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I have a program that needs to validate xml signatures, I have not had any troubles until a provider sent me one xml with a strange format and my code couldn't validate it's signature.

```
public bool Validate(XmlDocument p_doc)
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager l_nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        l_nsManager.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
        XmlElement l_signatureElement = p_doc.SelectSingleNode("//ds:Signature", l_nsManager) as XmlElement;
        SignedXml l_signed = new SignedXml(p_doc);
        l_signed.LoadXml(l_signatureElement);
        return l_signed.CheckSignature();
    }
```

The method CheckSignature returns false, and I know it is a valid document.
The xml I am trying to validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><EnvioCFE_entreEmpresas xmlns="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy EnvioCFE_entreEmpresasv1.32.xsd"><Caratula version="1.0"><RutReceptor>211162510010</RutReceptor><RUCEmisor>213217030011</RUCEmisor><Idemisor>58653</Idemisor><CantCFE>1</CantCFE><Fecha>2014-10-27T09:02:01.184-03:00</Fecha><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></Caratula><ns2:CFE_Adenda xmlns="http://tilsor.com.uy/#StringAdenda" xmlns:ns2="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy CFEEmpresas_v1.20.xsd"><CFE xmlns="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy CFEDGI_v1.19.xsd"><eFact><TmstFirma>2014-10-20T08:56:38.167-03:00</TmstFirma><Encabezado><IdDoc><TipoCFE>111</TipoCFE><Serie>A</Serie><Nro>20003</Nro><FchEmis>2014-10-16</FchEmis><PeriodoDesde>2014-06-30</PeriodoDesde><PeriodoHasta>2015-06-30</PeriodoHasta><FmaPago>1</FmaPago></IdDoc><Emisor><RUCEmisor>213217030011</RUCEmisor><RznSoc>Royal &amp; SunAlliance (Uruguay) S.A.</RznSoc><NomComercial>Royal &amp; SunAlliance Uruguay SA</NomComercial><GiroEmis>Seguros</GiroEmis><Telefono>29170505</Telefono><CorreoEmisor>dgi_cfe@uy.rsagroup.com</CorreoEmisor><EmiSucursal>RSA UY</EmiSucursal><CdgDGISucur>1</CdgDGISucur><DomFiscal>Sarandi 620</DomFiscal><Ciudad>Montevideo</Ciudad><Departamento>Montevideo</Departamento></Emisor><Receptor><TipoDocRecep>2</TipoDocRecep><CodPaisRecep>UY</CodPaisRecep><DocRecep>211162510010</DocRecep><RznSocRecep>PUNTO LUZ S.A.</RznSocRecep><DirRecep> SORIANO 1032</DirRecep><CiudadRecep>MONTEVIDEO</CiudadRecep><DeptoRecep>MONTEVIDEO</DeptoRecep><CP>0</CP></Receptor><Totales><TpoMoneda>UYU</TpoMoneda><TpoCambio>1.0000</TpoCambio><MntNoGrv>0.00</MntNoGrv><MntExpoyAsim>0.00</MntExpoyAsim><MntImpuestoPerc>0.00</MntImpuestoPerc><MntIVaenSusp>0.00</MntIVaenSusp><MntNetoIvaTasaMin>0.00</MntNetoIvaTasaMin><MntNetoIVATasaBasica>14754.10</MntNetoIVATasaBasica><MntNetoIVAOtra>0.00</MntNetoIVAOtra><IVATasaMin>10</IVATasaMin><IVATasaBasica>22</IVATasaBasica><MntIVATasaMin>0.00</MntIVATasaMin><MntIVATasaBasica>3245.90</MntIVATasaBasica><MntIVAOtra>0.00</MntIVAOtra><MntTotal>18000.00</MntTotal><MntTotRetenido>0.00</MntTotRetenido><CantLinDet>1</CantLinDet><MontoNF>0.00</MontoNF><MntPagar>18000.00</MntPagar></Totales></Encabezado><Detalle><Item><NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet><IndFact>3</IndFact><IndAgenteResp>R</IndAgenteResp><NomItem>DEDUCIBLE AUTOMOVILES/FLOTAS</NomItem><DscItem>POLIZA 619064</DscItem><Cantidad>1</Cantidad><UniMed>Unid</UniMed><PrecioUnitario>14754.10</PrecioUnitario><DescuentoPct>0.00</DescuentoPct><DescuentoMonto>0.00</DescuentoMonto><RecargoPct>0.00</RecargoPct><RecargoMnt>0.00</RecargoMnt><MontoItem>14754.10</MontoItem></Item></Detalle><DscRcgGlobal></DscRcgGlobal><MediosPago><MedioPago><NroLinMP>1</NroLinMP><GlosaMP>EFECTIVO</GlosaMP><ValorPago>18000.00</ValorPago></MedioPago></MediosPago><Referencia></Referencia><CAEData><CAE_ID>90140013992</CAE_ID><DNro>1</DNro><HNro>25000</HNro><FecVenc>2016-06-16</FecVenc></CAEData></eFact><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" >
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
<ds:XPath>
not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)
</ds:XPath>
</ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>Z1wbJ/j3XZ9IuC1d4SYnq2Y7pjE=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
de1w5zlI7BdJjdBpvTR/0aaDmonR7ICEVNEjvJDGk6MsvI8vs93M+wXIDcKJvm5RuRlrlR7W0TGY
8xP1WuiChOcAl5Fje9ExrvS1HPc+5NsguDFwGCBRWxs1gZP8coTkH596/cYsscM1I7XexoRLXHWS
TdghDNUJv7vNVQFTTXU=
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Correo Uruguayo - CA,OU=SERVICIOS ELECTRONICOS,O=ADMINISTRACION NACIONAL DE CORREOS,C=UY</ds:X509IssuerName>

<ds:X509SerialNumber>99998921932968755343991161283803277349</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</ds:X509IssuerSerial>
</ds:X509Data>
<ds:KeyValue>
<ds:RSAKeyValue>
<ds:Modulus>qhNCuOvb7x4Yr/0UAhvGG4TkgDc4G8zraH4KD6Rzm57npoGRpmFui+4ZcH/FxLVY906jkmn6YEEbu4O3CGep3/D9h60WAwSe29lDNyPVRNfnTy+syM9z+vVhwF5jqR3Eor1RuzkKqULPxWb45+KVq0dC/qsCQ9tMTQruWP/VIo0=</ds:Modulus>
<ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
</ds:RSAKeyValue>
</ds:KeyValue>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature></CFE><ns2:Adenda><data>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</data></ns2:Adenda></ns2:CFE_Adenda></EnvioCFE_entreEmpresas>
```

Thanks in advance for any anwser or suggestion

Comment: What errors do you get? Which line fails? See how to ask good questions on http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or your ticket might get closed .

Comment: There are no exceptions, the method CheckSignature() returns false, when I know this is a valid document.

Comment: @MartinDaFonte Did you ever arrive at a solution to this problem?